# Iterating through a list of imported classes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a bunch of classes representing tabs in a tab component. Each class has a static method called `title`. Here's the code using them:

```
import { Tab1, Tab2, Tab3, Tab4, Tab5} from '../../components';
var tab_classes = [
  Tab1,
  Tab2,
  Tab3,
  Tab4,
  Tab5
]

{tab_classes.map(tabclass =>
  <Tab className="nav-item">
    <a className="nav-link active" href="#">{tabclass.title()}</a>
  </Tab>
)}
```

It fails with `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined`. I did a mock test in console and it's definitely possible to stuff classes in a list and iterate through them that way. From this we conclude that the issue here is that they are imported (I removed `extend React...` and nothing happened). I don't know how import makes them different though.

Why does this code fail?

Comment: You may not have export `Tab1` to `Tab5` correctly in components.js. You can confirm it by `console.log(tabclass)`, which should print `undefined`

Comment: Any circular dependencies between the file and `../../components`?

Comment: @Bergi, you're the man! Post this as an answer and I'll mark it accepted. Many thanks. I had an import of this file at the start of `components/index.js`. Why was Webpack silent about it?

Comment: Does webpack usually warn about them? Circular dependencies are not an error, they can be pretty useful - but you have to deal with messed-up initialisation order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have a circular dependency between the file and `../../components` in your application structure. This would lead to the `var tabClasses` initialised with the array literal before the `TabN` components themselves are initialised, depending on which file is imported first.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you have typed the names of the classes in the import line correctly?

```
var {a, b, c} = {a: 1, b:2, d:4}
console.log(c) // -> undefined
```